# Autopairing to a device in BlueZ C

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, raspberry-pi3

What I need to do is to automatically accept pairing requests while I am discoverable using the `libbluetooth` library for C provided by BlueZ. The program that this needs to be done in will be run as a service on start up of a Raspberry Pi 3 and handles configuring the Pi via another program written for Android so that the user doesn't have to have a spare keyboard, mouse, and monitor lying around.

I need to be able to bypass pin authentication, but if I could authenticate in some other way via only code, it would be a plus. It would also be helpful if I could cause the Pi to remain discoverable until a connection is established via bluetooth.

I am newer to using the `libbluetooth` library and C, so any example code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you don't use libbluetooth for this. In addition to not being an officially supported library it will be very difficult to implement what you want using libbluetooth. The "normal" way to do what you want is via the bluez DBUS [agent api](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/doc/agent-api.txt).

Comment: Can you please place your comment within an answer so that I can mark it as being the right one. I also found that after removing Blueman the Pi would simply accept any pairing requests sent its way.